# NServiceBus in mixed environment

Tags: nservicebus

Is there a way to use NSB in a mixed environment (not all .NET) where the various parts of the system can share messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options in this regard.  First you can expose any NSB endpoint via WCF to allow non .NET components to get messages onto NSB.  You may then return messages to the other components by also sending messages to a gateway endpoint that makes similar calls into the non .NET components via a .NET compatible API or service.

Secondly it is possible to write your own transport that could bridge over to another world.  What I mean is that you could supply a JMS implementation that would run instead of MSMQ.  You would still have to pick up the messages on your own on the other side.

Lastly we've seen people setup what is known as a Satellite in NSB to handle bridging to other systems via another ESB/Broker.  A Satellite runs along side an endpoint with its own resources.  You may consider setting up a full blown endpoint just to create this bridge.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, but the full features of NSB will really be available to the .NET components of your environment. Your NSB system can be extended to other non-.net components in your system via integration points.

Comment: Interesting. Just getting started with NSB, but would be interested in what would be lost to the non-.NET pieces?  It could only send stuff to the bus and subscribed resources could handle?  Could send but not receive?

Comment: @coach_rob: The first issue is interopability. A message defined in NSB will not be the same as the message in your Java(?) app. A certain level of translation needs to take place. Then you need to push that "new" message to your Java app so it can consume it. The same if your Java app wants to send a command to NSB. To get the Java message on the buss it needs to be translated and handled, generally via a SendLocal command. There are other scenarios / techniques of course.

Answer (score 1):

The upcoming 4.0 release will contain support for using SqlServer, ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ as transports. With this we hope to address the need to use NServiceBus in a mixed environment.